# Adding information for coversion between formats

Tags: lyx, conversion

I just installed LyX 2.2.0, and trying to preview the included `examples/splash.lyx` file that shows up the first time you start the program. I'm getting an error about not being able to convert between image formats.

[image: No information for converting svg format files to pdf6. Define a converter in the preferences]

In `Lyx -> Preferences -> File Handling -> Converters` I don't see any existing definition for SVG to PDF6. I'm not sure how I should add a new converter though. I can select SVG from the `From format:`, but there are many different PDF options from the `To format:`. None of which are named PDF6. Should I be using PDF (graphics)? And then I'm not sure what command to use. For example EPS -> PDF (graphics) uses

```
epstopdf --outfile=$$o $$i
```

I tried adding a new definition to go from SVG -> PDF (graphics) and using the command `svgtopdf --outfile=$$o $$i`, but I also got an error.

[image]

Comment: PDF (graphics) is the right one to look at. You can see this if you go to File Formats (just below Converters) and go to PDF (graphics). It shows "pdf6". I don't know why your command is not working. I recommend the following: 1. exit LyX. 2. back up your preferences file (in your user directory which is listed in Help > About), then delete that file (remember you already backed it up right?). 3. Install rsvg-convert (if you happen to be on ubuntu just run `sudo apt-get install librsvg2-bin`). 4. Open LyX and go to "Reconfigure". 5. restart LyX. Does it work now?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I am facing the same problem as OP.

Comment: same issue just appeared out of nothing ...

Comment: This link works for me: https://wiki.lyx.org/Tips/UseInkscapeSVGImages

Comment: For Inkscape 1.0+r73+1 I had to adjust my export command to `inkscape --export-area-drawing $$i --export-filename=$$o`